# How to avoid weird artifacts which only appear with ray-tracing enabled with Blender Render?

Tags: artifacts, rendering

What's the cause of the weird, checkerboarding on the purple spheres and how do I remove it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "ray-tracing" enabled? Are you using Cycles, Eevee or Blender Internal? Do you have a texture applied?

Comment: can you include the blend file, as of right now you question is ununderstandable

Comment: @rjg Sorry, sort of floundering around here. 1) When the ray-tracing checkbox in the shading panel is checked. 2) Blender Internal. 3) No texture applied. Thanks for your help

Comment: @DrachenSeele sorry, added it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by [z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting) in overlaping surfaces. Remove double geometry to resolve it.

[image]